# dd/fallocate-smiliar function in perl

Tags: perl, file, dd, fallocate

I have a line like `dd if=/dev/zero of=myImg.img bs=1KB count=1024k` , which I have to do several times in my script. Therefore i wanted to integrate this line in my perl script, not by doing a `system('...');` call, but by creating a funktion. Is there a good way to do so?

I've tried it with [MakeMaker](http://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html), but i didn't find a proper way to set my filelength/offset the right way, or anything similar to the `-o -l` from `fallocate`. 
And of course, the obvious way `open(FH,">/myFolder/MyImg.img");` didn't work, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fallocate(1)` has the advantage of being much faster than the pure-Perl way of writing out a gigabyte of zero bytes. It uses a Linux-specific syscall that does have a POSIX equivalent but unfortunately that's not implemented by the `POSIX` module.
If you can use sparse files (the only application I can think of right now that really doesn't like them is using the files as swap space), the easiest way is to call `truncate($fh, $size)`. But of course you do need to open the file for writing first -- why didn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

Your question amounts to the following:

> *How can I create a 1,000 MiB file of NUL bytes in Perl?*

You could use the following:

```
open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

for (1..1000) {
   print($fh "\0" x (1024*1024))
      or die("Error writing to \"$qfn\": $!\n");
}

close($fh)
   or die("Error writing to \"$qfn\": $!\n");
```

(Ok, so that's really equivalent to `bs=1024k count=1KB`, but the result is the same, and it's faster than `bs=1KB count=1024k` for both `dd` and for `perl`.)